# Helm 3.0 Error: Error: UPGRADE FAILED: secrets "sh.helm.release.v1.eks-test-app-dev.vX" is forbidden

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am building a cicd for kubernetes(EKS) with Helm in AWS. In general, what I do is, package the helm chart as template, and then, deploy with upgrade using that package plus some variables.

My issue come when deploying an already deployed chart, if I change the nameOverride value in the values.yml(identified as ${CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_appsource}/${HELM_PROJECT_VALUES_PATH}/${ENV}/${HELM_VALUES_FILE_NAME}) which should just increase the revision and change the names of k8s resources, but instead its throwing the following error:

```
[Container] 2022/09/13 12:19:28 Running command helm upgrade ${APP_NAME} *.tgz --install -n ${NAMESPACE} \
  -f ${CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_appsource}/${HELM_PROJECT_VALUES_PATH}/${ENV}/${HELM_VALUES_FILE_NAME} \
  -f output.yaml --set-string env=${ENV},image.tag=${APP_VERSION} --timeout 10m0s --debug

history.go:56: [debug] getting history for release eks-test-app-dev
upgrade.go:142: [debug] preparing upgrade for eks-test-app-dev
upgrade.go:150: [debug] performing update for eks-test-app-dev
upgrade.go:322: [debug] creating upgraded release for eks-test-app-dev
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: secrets "sh.helm.release.v1.eks-test-app-dev.v8" is forbidden: User "build" cannot delete resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "dev"
helm.go:84: [debug] secrets "sh.helm.release.v1.eks-test-app-dev.v8" is forbidden: User "build" cannot delete resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "dev"
UPGRADE FAILED
main.newUpgradeCmd.func2
    helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/upgrade.go:199
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.3.0/command.go:856
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.3.0/command.go:974
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.3.0/command.go:902
main.main
    helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/helm.go:83
runtime.main
    runtime/proc.go:255
runtime.goexit
    runtime/asm_amd64.s:1581
```

That secret is not something I generated, seems to be a secret automatically generated from Helm.

The worst part is that, running the same exact command from my computer works as expected.

Some extra info:

- Helm version: version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.8.1", GitCommit:"5cb9af4b1b271d11d7a97a71df3ac337dd94ad37", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.17.5"}
- Running before the upgrade command on the cicd: helm history ${APP_NAME} -n ${NAMESPACE}

```
REVISION    UPDATED                     STATUS      CHART       APP VERSION DESCRIPTION     
8           Tue Sep 13 12:20:19 2022    superseded  app-0.0.1               Upgrade complete
9           Tue Sep 13 12:22:12 2022    superseded  app-0.0.1               Upgrade complete
10          Tue Sep 13 12:22:36 2022    superseded  app-0.0.1               Upgrade complete
11          Tue Sep 13 12:23:42 2022    superseded  app-0.0.1               Upgrade complete
12          Tue Sep 13 12:54:22 2022    superseded  app-0.0.1               Upgrade complete
13          Tue Sep 13 12:56:31 2022    superseded  app-0.0.1               Upgrade complete
14          Tue Sep 13 13:08:54 2022    superseded  app-0.0.1               Upgrade complete
15          Tue Sep 13 13:19:00 2022    superseded  app-0.0.1               Upgrade complete
16          Tue Sep 13 14:15:24 2022    superseded  app-0.0.1               Upgrade complete
17          Tue Sep 13 14:17:05 2022    deployed    app-0.0.1               Upgrade complete
```

For me it seems that upgrade somehow its failing to synchronise with all the previous revisions. But I´m totally at lost. Any hint on which is the issue?

Comment: Helm keeps its state in the cluster in Kubernetes Secret objects.  The error you're getting is not anything to do with your chart _per se_, but that RBAC rules prevent the entity running Helm from cleaning up a very old release Secret.

Comment: So the issue is the user performing the actions. Its trying to delete old revisions before starting. Make sense, I was too focused that was helm issue, I´ll review the user permissions. Thank you.